# Examples of wrong proof by induction

Tags: proof-writing, induction, proof-explanation

Could someone provide a *wrong clime* and  its *wrong proof by induction* so that only the first step be wrong?

Comment: [All horses are the same color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_horses_are_the_same_color).

Answer (score 0):

For all $n \in \Bbb N$, show that $n > n+1$. Skip step $1$ and assume that for $n \geq 2$, that $n > n+1$. Then let $n = k+1$, whence $(k+1) + 1 < (k) + 1 = k+1$, clearly wrong.